# Correct way to add a SRV record to Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, srv-record

I'm trying to add records needed to get my email working. When I try to add the SRV record to Google Cloud, the data text field template has only 3 numbers and a text ?? But on godaddy there are these fields that need to be add:

Port, Protocol, Name, Service, Priority, Weight, Target.
here is an example from godaddy:

```
443 _tls    @   _sip    100 1   some-thing.some-thing
```

Here is Google Cloud records form:
[image]

So how should I add these data properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a `SRV` [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) - which contains the `SRV` data:

```
Port Protocol Name Service Priority Weight Target
5060     _tls    @    _sip      100      1 some-thing.some-thing
```

the format is `_service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port target.`

taken apart, might use name `_sip._tcp.acme.com.` with `SRV` data alike:

```
0 1 5060 sip.acme.com.
```

notice the trailing `.`